# How to fetch immidiate next element of array in PHP

Tags: php

I have array of following form

```
$a = array(
      [0] => 
      [address_country] => 
      [1] => 2011-11-29 14:49:10
      [createdtime] => 2011-11-29 14:49:10
    )
```

I am parsing this array using a for loop

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++){

}
```

Now I want retrieve key of 2nd element as I parse it

`For if i = 0`, then i need some way of knowing that it's corresponding column name is `address_country`

Is there any way for this?

Please note I have to stick with for loop only

Comment: Can you post your proper array structure ?

Comment: use `foreach()` when having loops, makes retrieval easier

Comment: nope array_search won't help me, as I need to retrieve immidiate next key name

Comment: @shankar It is already there

Comment: See [next](http://in2.php.net/next).

Comment: You can just call `each()` twice... `reset($a);while(($first=each($a)) && ($second = each($a))){...}`.

Comment: I tried, but not sure, it is not returning anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys):

```
$a = array(
      0 => '',
      'address_country' => '',
      '1' => '2011-11-29 14:49:10',
      'createdtime' => '2011-11-29 14:49:10'
    );

$keys = array_keys($a);
$i    = 1;
$m    = count($keys);

foreach($a as $key=>$value)
{
   echo(sprintf('My key is [%s] and my next neighbor key is [%s]'.PHP_EOL, $key, $i<$m?$keys[$i++]:null));
}
```

this will result in

```
My key is [0] and my next neighbor key is [address_country]
My key is [address_country] and my next neighbor key is [1]
My key is [1] and my next neighbor key is [createdtime]
My key is [createdtime] and my next neighbor key is []
```

note, that for last element next key will be treated as `null`

Answer (score 0):

try this. I think this is what you want

```
$c = array_values($a);
for($i = 0; $i < count($c); $i++){
    if(count($c)-1 > ($i)) {
   if(array_search($c[$i+1],$a) == "address_country")
   echo "found";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to make things hard coded,